# Possible to control a reusable component individual instance's state from another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

Okay, I'm having a bad case of "coder's block"....I can't solve this issue, or see an alternative to it.
I Have my main App.js component, 4 similar reusable components, BlueH... etc

A useCounter hook, and a reusable  component, This is reused 30 times and
displayed in 2 tables. inside of

Normally just having the button for the start/stop timer methods inside of the 
component, would be fine, it's all self contained, they all operate individually.

However....for this particular case, I need to be able to control each individual instance of  via a button from a portal containing buttons.

there are 30 in total between BlueH,GreenV,GreenH,BlueV, each of these have their own

I can't see the solution or if there is another method of achieving this ... and been lost since yesterday morning.

Code is below, if anyone can point me in the right direction, It would be greatly appreciated.

```
const App = () => {
 // irrelevant code //
  return (
    <>
       <div className={styles.parent}>
         <div className={styles.t1} onClick={() => setActive("1")}>
           <BlueH active={active} id="1" />
         </div>
         <div className={styles.t2} onClick={() => setActive("2")}>
           <BlueV active={active} id="2" />
         </div>
         <div className={styles.t3} onClick={() => setActive("3")}>
           <GreenH active={active} id="3" />
         </div>
         <div className={styles.t4} onClick={() => setActive("4")}>
           <GreenV active={active} id="4" />
         </div>
         <TableContainerComponent />
       </div>
    </>
 )
}
```

The button that I want to control the state of each individual instance of my Counter is inside my  reusable component, it's wrapped in a portal and already controls different instances of state in the BlueH, GreenV...etc reusable components.

there are 30 in total between BlueH,GreenV,GreenH,BlueV, each of these have their own Timer

```
const TableContainerComponent = ({ active }) => {

  const { hourlyRate, dayRate, nightRate, satRate } = useGlobalContext();

  function createData(table, rate, timer) {
    return {table, rate, timer }
}

const data = [
  createData(
    "30",
    hourlyRate === dayRate
      ? "Day"
      : hourlyRate === nightRate
        ? "Night"
        : hourlyRate === satRate
          ? "Fri/Sat"
          : "VIP",
    <Counter key='30' />
  ),
  createData(
    "31",
    hourlyRate === dayRate
      ? "Day"
      : hourlyRate === nightRate
        ? "Night"
        : hourlyRate === satRate
          ? "Fri/Sat"
          : "VIP",
    <Counter key='31' />
  )
]

return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.div}>
        <TableContainer component={Paper} className={styles.tableContainer}>
          <Table className={styles.table}>
            <TableHeadStyled className={styles.thead}>
              <TableCell className={styles.td}>Table</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={styles.td}>Rate</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={styles.td}>
                Timer&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$$$
              </TableCell>
            </TableHeadStyled>
            <TableBody>
              {data.map((data) => (
                <TableRowStyled className={styles.tr} key={data.table}>
                  <TableCell className={styles.td}>Table&nbsp;{data.table}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={styles.td}>&nbsp;{data.rate}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={styles.td}>{data.timer}</TableCell>
                </TableRowStyled>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.div2}>
        <TableContainer component={Paper} className={styles.tableContainer}>
          <Table className={styles.table}>
            <TableHeadStyled className={styles.thead}>
              <TableCell className={styles.td}>Table</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={styles.td}>Rate</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={styles.td}>
                Timer&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$$$
              </TableCell>
            </TableHeadStyled>
            <TableBody>
              {data2.map((data2) => (
                <TableRowStyled className={styles.tr} key={data2.table}>
                  <TableCell className={styles.td}>
                    Table&nbsp;{data2.table}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={styles.td}>&nbsp;{data2.rate}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={styles.td}>{data2.timer}</TableCell>
                </TableRowStyled>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TableContainerComponent;
```

useCounter.js

```
import { useGlobalContext } from "./Context";
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
const useCounter = (start, reset, id) => {
  const {
    hourlyRate,
  } = useGlobalContext();
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);
  const [prepaidAmount, setPrepaidAmount] = useState(20);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false)
  const intervalId = useRef(null);
  let uniqueId = id

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isRunning) {
      intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
        setSeconds((prevSeconds) => prevSeconds - 1);
        if (prepaidAmount > 0 && seconds <= 0) {
          setAmount((prevAmount) => +(prevAmount + (hourlyRate / 3600)).toFixed(2));
        } else {
          setAmount((prevAmount) => +(prevAmount - (hourlyRate / 3600)).toFixed(2));
        }
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId.current);
  }, [isRunning, prepaidAmount, seconds]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (prepaidAmount > 0) {
      const prepaidTime = (prepaidAmount / hourlyRate) * 3600;
      setSeconds(prepaidTime);
      setAmount(prepaidAmount);
      setPrepaidAmount(prepaidAmount);
    }
  }, [prepaidAmount, hourlyRate]);


  const handleReset = () => {
    setIsRunning(false);                                                                                                                                                                            
    setSeconds(0);
    setAmount(0);
    setPrepaidAmount(0);
  };
  
  const handleStart = () => {
    setIsRunning(true)
  }

  const handleStop = () => {
    setIsRunning(false)
  }

  return {
    seconds,
    amount,
    prepaidAmount,
    isRunning,
    handleReset,
    handleStart,
    handleStop,
    uniqueId
  }
};

export { useCounter }
```

```
const BlueH = ({
    textAlign,
    id,
    active,
    onSetStart,
    handleStartTimer,
    timer,
}) => {
function onFetch(...args) {
        const { response, error } = useFetch(...args)
        return response, error
    }
    const [isFramePopupOpen, setFramePopupOpen] = useState(false)
    const openFramePopup = useCallback(() => {
        setFramePopupOpen(true)
    }, [])
    const closeFramePopup = useCallback(() => {
        setFramePopupOpen(false)
    }, [])
    const [status, setStatus] = useState({
        booked: false,
        reserved: false,
        disabled: false,
    })
    const handleBook = () => {
        setStatus((prevStatus) => ({
            ...prevStatus,
            booked: true,
        }))
        onFetch(active, "on")
    }
    const handleClose = () => {
        setStatus((prevStatus) => ({
            ...prevStatus,
            booked: false,
        }))
        onFetch(active, "off")
        handleStop()
        handleReset()
    }
    const handleReserve = () => {
        setStatus((prevStatus) => ({
            ...prevStatus,
            reserved: !prevStatus.reserved,
        }))
    }
    const handleDisable = () => {
        setStatus((prevStatus) => ({
            ...prevStatus,
            disabled: !prevStatus.disabled,
        }))
    }
    const handleFlash = () => {
        onFetch(active, flash)
    }

return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.div}>
                <button className={styles.button} onClick={openFramePopup} />
                <div className={styles.div1} style={{ left: textAlign }}>
                    {id}
                </div>
                {status.reserved && <ReservedH />}
                {status.booked && <BookedH />}
                {status.disabled && <DisabledH />}
            </div>
            <div>
                <ShowCounter
                    prepaidAmount={prepaidAmount}
                    amount={amount}
                    seconds={seconds}
                    isRunning={isRunning}
                    handleStart={handleStart}
                    uniqueId={uniqueId}
                />
                {isFramePopupOpen && (
                    <PortalPopup
                        placement="Centered"
                        onOutsideClick={closeFramePopup}
                    ></PortalPopup>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default BlueH

const ShowCounter = ({ prepaidAmount, seconds, amount }) => {

    return (
        <div className={styles.timerdiv}>
            <span style={{ color: prepaidAmount > 0 ? "#CA0900" : "black" }}>
                {formatTime(Math.abs(seconds))}
            </span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span style={{ color: prepaidAmount > 0 ? "#CA0900" : "black" }}>
                {prepaidAmount > 0
                    ? `- $${amount.toFixed(2)}`
                    : `$${amount.toFixed(2)}`}
            </span>
            {/* <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={handleStop}>Stop</button>
            <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button> */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Buttons.js

```
const Buttons = ({ handleReserve, handleDisable, handleBook, handleClose, handleFlash, active }) => {

  return (
    <>
        <div className={styles.notesParent}>
          <button className={styles.notes}>
            <div className={styles.allOnWrapper}>
              <div className={styles.allOn}>Notes</div>
            </div>
          </button>
          <button className={styles.close} onClick={handleClose}>
            <div className={styles.allOnWrapper}>
              <div className={styles.allOn}>Close</div>
            </div>
          </button>
          <button key={active} className={styles.book} onClick={handleBook}>
            <div className={styles.allOnWrapper}>
              <div className={styles.allOn}>Book</div>
            </div>
          </button>
          <button className={styles.flash} onClick={handleFlash}>
            <div className={styles.allOnWrapper}>
              <div className={styles.allOn}>Flash</div>
            </div>
          </button>
          <button className={styles.reserve} onClick={() => handleReserve()}>
            <div className={styles.allOnWrapper}>
              <div className={styles.allOn}>Reserve</div>
            </div>
          </button>
          <button className={styles.disable} onClick={() => handleDisable()}>
            <button className={styles.buttonsButton}>
              <div className={styles.allOn}>Disable</div>
            </button>
          </button>
        </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Buttons;
```

and I have a useCounter hook, and a reusable Counter component, This is reused, 30 times and
displayed in 2 tables. inside of

I have tried pasing props around, lifting up the state and trying to use keys or unique id's... But nothing seems to work, I do have a feeling I'm missing something very obvious right infront of me, but it's just been a long week haha.

apologies, I'll include the full code.

Comment: It looks like your counter takes a callback called handleStart, which you don't seem to be providing, which presumably is going to change seconds or something, which you also are not providing. What happens if you provide seconds and increment it from outside your counter?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship updated my post to include all relevant code, minus the imports, but that's not the issue, If I use the buttons commented out in Counter.js they all operate with their own instance of state, but I can't solve my issue of needing to have the button / handlevent logic in a seperate component, no matter what I do they end up using the same instance of state, And I don't know how to hint to react that they are not the same otherwise.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That's the thing, though. You can only give access to your component's internal state by passing it out through a callback. But since you're already passing values and callbacks _in_, it's easier and cleaner to just store those values at the higher level and make your components dumb components that only display what they're provided from the outside. This would simplify the whole situation quite a bit.